# Javadoc formatter as pretty as readthedocs/sphinx?

Tags: java, python, javadoc, python-sphinx

When I think of Java automatic documentation, I think, well, ugly. Not that it's not useful, but I've been spoiled by readthedocs / sphinx. Is there a package that makes your javadocs pretty?

- example of ugly: http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/sphinx4/javadoc/
- example of pretty: http://pyjnius.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html

No offense to the creators of javadoc. It's just clear that function was the focus, and not form.

Comment: Odd, I consider Javadoc pretty.  They did release new stylesheets a year or so ago, but it's still pretty much the same: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/

Comment: Maybe you could elaborate on what makes the second example "pretty"?  Is it just that the colors look more modern?

Comment: hmmm thanks for the link @CoryKendall . That's better than I had feared. One huge thing is the use of frames -- it positively shouts 1995. Perhaps usablility is more what I'm looking at (which can be terribly subjective); for example: having a table of contents.. hmm I guess I need to think about this more :)

Comment: @JaredForsyth Ironically the new CSS breaks my workflow, making it less functional for me!  In the old style in firefox, I could type `/ String<CR>F6<Space>` to jump to the definition of a String and scroll through the available methods.  With the new style, this doesn't work at all :(

Comment: It seems like they could work a bit on usability so that your very common use case didn't require resorting to a page search...